# Having issue setting up access token from policy in Vault

Tags: docker, access-token, policy, hashicorp-vault

I am setting up Hashicorp vault on my development environment in -dev mode and trying to use access token created from policies to access to secret which policy is created for but I get "*permission denied" while I try to access to secret from CLI or API. Based on Vault [documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/acl.html) it should work.
The following is what I have done to set up:

1. Set up docker container using `docker run --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -p 8200:8200 -e 'VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=roottoken' -v //c/confi
   g:/config vault`
2. Connect to docker container using `docker exec -it {docker name} ash`. I know it should be **bash** command but bash doesn't work and **ash** works!
3. After bashing to docker, `export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'`
4. Set the root token in environment variable `export VAULT_TOKEN='roottoken'`
5. Create a secret `vault secret/foo/bar value=secret`
6. Create a policy file called secret.hcl with the content `path "secret/foo/*" {
   policy = "read"
   }`
7. Create a policy for the secret `vault policy-write secret /config/secret.hcl` and make sure the policy is created
8. Create a token for the policy is just created `vault token-create -policy="secret"`
9. Try to access the policy using API 'http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/foo' passing X-Vault-Token='token created in step 8' in header
10. Getting "*permission denied" error

Would be great is someone can shed a light..

Comment: Rather than hitting the api directly, can you access it by `export VAULT_TOKEN='secrettoken'` and then `vault read secret/foo/bar` and can you read it with the root token using the api? Just want to narrow down that the policy is the problem.

Comment: I can read it with root token. and have tried exporting VAULT_TOKEN but no succes

Comment: From your description, what you've done should work. Rather than describing your steps and paraphrasing output, an actual copy/paste of all the commands and their output may help. The problem appears to be either in your token, the binding of the policy to the token, or the policy itself. You've at least ruled out that it's not the api call or the saving of the data in vault.

Comment: I have already listed all the commands I executed. The problem is there is not much documentation around Vault.